# dataframe/numpy array conversion in Databricks ' Deep Learning Pipelines: scalability issue?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, deep-learning, databricks

Databricks' Deep Learning Pipelines is a Spark package with Python API which aims to enable Deep Learning models from Tensorflow/Keras to run on Spark and take `DataFrame` as inputs.

This sounds cool, since this would enable to run image recognition (notably) in a distributed way on a distributed dataset, thus ensuring scalability.

However, upon reading the code of the `sparkdl` package (the Python library of Deep Learning Pipelines) on [Github](https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning/tree/master/python/sparkdl), I observed a few things which make me question how scalable the whole thing might be.

First of all, `sparkdl` uses as input a folder of images (which need e.g. to be classified) and loads it into a Spark `DataFrame`.

Then, in order to train a deep learning model on these images, the "fit" method of `sparkdl`, does the following things.

1. It converts the `DataFrame` to a 4D `numpy` array (#dataset_size,
   Height, Width, #channel) using the collect() method of Spark
   `DataFrames`. Thus, at this stage the whole data is stored in the
   driver node.
2. broadcast this 4D `numpy` array to every worker node using Spark's `broadcast()` function.
3. perform the actual training (e.g. through `model.fit()` in Keras) using as input the broadcast array.

I understand that the above process ensures that the training is done in a distributed fashion, since each node uses local data.
But converting the `DataFrame` (which contains all of your data, mind you) into a `numpy` array using collect makes the memory the bottleneck (not only at driver node, but also at each worker node).

So in the end, we cannot process a dataset larger than what a single machine can handle. We probably get a speed improvement at the training stage, but we cannot leverage the main advantage of Spark (i.e. dealing with "big" data, requiring by nature distributed storage).

Databricks has very smart people working months on such project, so I guess there must be more to this than I perceive.

The main reason I suspect this `numpy` conversion takes place is that the Keras models usually take as input a multidimensional array, while `DataFrames` can store at best 1D arrays.

I am not an expert of Spark and distributed computing, so I am looking for someone to tell me if I am missing something here and/or if I am completely wrong.

Thank you for reading. First post here, please let me know if I can improve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're describing [`KerasImageFileEstimator`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning/blob/3f668d9b4a0aa2ef6fe05df5bf5c1d705cd2530d/python/sparkdl/estimators/keras_image_file_estimator.py#L39) and in that case your observation is correct and it is indeed limited to datasets, that can be stored in local memory. The purpose of this `Estimator` is not to distribute over the data, but to [distribute over a setparameters](https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning/blob/3f668d9b4a0aa2ef6fe05df5bf5c1d705cd2530d/python/sparkdl/estimators/keras_image_file_estimator.py#L259) and create multiple models for a single dataset. These can can be later used for example to create ensemble models or for hyperparameter tuning. Essentially Spark is used here as a glorified task queue.

In its behavior it is similar to other tools from Databricks, like [`spark-sklearn`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn) or methods from other packages, like [Distributed Keras](https://github.com/cerndb/dist-keras).

However this behavior doesn't apply to all tools provided by `spark-deep-learning`. For example [`DeepImagePredictor`](https://github.com/databricks/spark-deep-learning/blob/3f668d9b4a0aa2ef6fe05df5bf5c1d705cd2530d/python/sparkdl/transformers/named_image.py#L35) uses Python `udfs` to distribute processing over the data.